# Angular *ngFor : access next element's data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using angular to display *schedules* data set.

Now, between two consecutive schedules, if there is a time gap, I need to add some additional data that represents the time gap and displays the interval between the two.

For this purpose, I need to access the next object's data in the for loop. Refer to this example :

```
...
<ng-container *ngFor="let schedule in schedules; let i=index; let last=last">
    ...
    <ng-container *ngIf="!last && (schedule[i].end_time < schedule[i+1].start_time)">
        ...
        There is a gap of {{schedule[i+1].start_time - schedule[i].end_time}}
        ...
    </ng-container>
    ...
</ng-container>
...
```

I have created two simple functions on this component using typescript. One returns the boolean value for each schedule by comparison (for *ngIf), the other returns the time interval between this schedule and the next and prints the value.

But I want to know if there is any *neat* way to access data of the next object in the for loop? like `schedule[i+1]`

Thanks

Comment: I would add new parameter inside schedules and do the calculations inside typescript itself. binding can be very easy in this scenario.

Comment: so apparently there is no way to access object's data by their index? maybe they should include this as a feature.

Comment: There are many ways, You can access by index, but as I said this can be very tricky as you don't know what index have the data what not. I think you can use `ng-template` too,.